# Are there any verified cases of patients that stopped wearing prescription glasses due to a spontaneous remission of a visual impairment?

Tags: ophthalmology, medical-records, history, blurry-vision

I would like to know if there are medically verified records of individuals prescribed with eyeglasses for years, who eventually experienced a spontaneous remission of their visual impairments, rendering their prescription glasses no longer necessary.

The closest to what I'm asking that I managed to find are the following peer-reviewed papers:

- Spontaneous remission of paraneoplastic ocular flutter and saccadic intrusions (https://doi.org/10.1212/WNL.38.3.499)
- Recovery From Poststroke Visual Impairment: Evidence From a Clinical Trials Resource (https://doi.org/10.1177%2F1545968312454683)
- Cushing's Disease in a Patient With a 'Nonfunctioning' Pituitary Tumor Spontaneous Development and Remission (https://doi.org/10.1001/archinte.1983.00350050206041)

Unfortunately, none of these papers mentions a visual condition that required wearing prescription glasses and the cessation of their use after spontaneous remission. That said, I'm personally very far from being an expert at searching the literature of medical sciences, and in no way do I claim to have exhaustively explored all available literature. Thus, in hope that someone more knowledgeable might help me out, I ask:

Are there any verified cases of patients who experienced a spontaneous visual impairment remission that freed them from the need to wear prescription glasses?

---

**[Optional]** In case you may be wondering why I'm asking such a question in the first place, the reason is the following: I've watched lots of live recordings of faith healing services in which people come forward to testify about all sorts of healings. In particular, one category of testimonies that puzzles me the most is the one involving individuals who used to wear prescription glasses for years coming forward to testify about how they are now able to see very well, holding their glasses in their hands, sometimes in tears, sometimes putting on and off their glasses again and again to confirm to their own astonishment that the healing has really taken place. For the curious, here are a few video clips of what I'm talking about: [example 1](https://youtu.be/5gC3x51u4YU?t=139), [example 2](https://youtu.be/YVcTCooxEFY?t=43), [example 3](https://youtu.be/WYU-ClYZQvg?t=51), [example 4](https://youtu.be/auxemjReJ50?t=2979), [example 5](https://youtu.be/cf3FLfddT8Q?t=84), [example 6](https://youtu.be/Hqe26pm2Vbo?t=83).

Comment: What research have you done on this? Research into claims of faith healings don't count. This is a medical sciences site, not a mysticism site, and what we require is prior research into the **science** of your questions. I see none in this question.

Comment: @CareyGregory good point, I actually did search for a little while and found a couple of papers on spontaneous remissions, concretely, a paper about the spontaneous remission of [ocular flatter](https://n.neurology.org/content/38/3/499.short) and another about the spontaneous remission of [hypercorticolism](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/article-abstract/603184). Unfortunately, the later seems to be a false positive and the former does not mention a condition that required wearing prescription glasses for years. Should I cite these papers nonetheless in the question?

Comment: Yes, any research you've done on the science side needs to be in the question. Stuff in comments never counts on any SE site because comments aren't subject to voting and can be deleted at any time for almost any reason. I really think you would benefit from taking the [tour].

Comment: @CareyGregory what do you think now?